# How important is to reuse background drawables?

Tags: android, optimization, button, resources, android-drawable

I have many buttons on screen at a time, each one has a background `Drawable` that I create on the fly. There are 7 types of backgrounds to choose from.

I am wondering if I should implement a reuse map for those drawables, have only one of each type created and reuse it on buttons of the same type (very much like `ListView` reuses layouts for rows)

On the other hand is much **easier** for me to just create a separate `Drawable` for each button, even if the type is repeated.

Any arguments in favor/opposing these approaches?
(Note: I don't want to start a discussion, this is not that kind of forum, just to get practical programming reasons to go either way, like memory usage, speed, compatibility, etc.)

Comment: I posted a link in the answer to one of your questions, in each it was explained that the drawables share a certain state so your concern are not valid. Anyway I don't see how your map would help if the buttons are at the same time on the screen.

Comment: @Luksprog It is my understanding that if a member of class `MyView` is `Drawable mBg` and the assignment during instantiation `mBg = mymap.get("RedButton");`, then the drawable is not cloned, but a reference to the same drawable in the map. Since `Drawable` is a class and not a simple type like `float` or `int` I presume there is some memory saving if the number of buttons is large.

Comment: The memory saved would be small as the drawable would share the common state(for example, in the case of a `BitmapDrawable` the bitmap will be shared). Also when a drawable is set on a view that view registers itself as a callback for the drawable so in your case the drawable will reference only the last view on which is set). I would not bother with this and just use a different drawable.

Comment: @Luksprog I appreciate your input very much and will use it when I have to choose the final code for my buttons.